# JPA: Locking a parent object to prevent multiple children being created

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

I am using JPA with EclipseLink and MySQL to manage my data and I want to prevent my application creating two child objects that are not compatible.

My current logic which does not work looks like this.

1. Start transaction with `REPEATABLE_READ` isolation.
2. Fetch and lock Account object using a `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` lock.
3. Read existing Address objects from returned Account object using a `@OneToMany` field.
4. Ensure no two addresses are marked as `Primary` - update an existing one if the new Address is `Primary`.
5. Add the new Address object to the Account object.
6. Complete the transaction.

However after this, if two requests are made within a few milliseconds of each other, I end up with two addresses marked as `Primary` which is not what I expected.

I wonder whether I need to change my isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE` but I'm concerned about the impact this might have on my throughput for unrelated Accounts.

Comment: I don't know JPA, but sounds like PESSIMISTIC_WRITE will not in fact lock until you update Account.  Does PESSIMISTIC_READ work?  probably not, if that does a shared lock

Comment: Pessimistic locks are supposed to lock immediately. From https://docs.oracle.com/javaee%2F7%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html "The lock modes LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE, and LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT are used to immediately obtain long-term database locks."

Comment: In MySQL it uses `FOR UPDATE` on the read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: I would guess that the cache(s) are in play: check if the second process is using a different cached entity instance that might have been read in before you made the changes in the first transaction. You might need to refresh the entity instance in the second transaction to ensure all changes made since it was last read are visible. JPA provides the entity manager 'refresh' method, but you can also use query hints to have your provider force the refresh if you want to pass it in with the pessimistic locking query.

Comment: It's not the cache but the fact that a "repeatable read" means all reads will use the data at the start of the transaction - which was before the update. I switched to Serializable (which locks reads as well as writes) and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is the "lost update" situation which `SERIALIZABLE` isolation is designed to avoid.

`REPEATABLE_READ` is designed to ensure that multiple reads in a transaction will return the values from the start of that transaction, so the second transaction doesn't see the UPDATE performed by the first transaction. It only sees the version of rows in the Address table as they were when transaction 2 started (before the update was committed by transaction 1).

I could use `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level, so transaction 2 does a SELECT on the Address table and sees the most recent committed change, however that would allow queries in a single transaction to read inconsistent data.

I would like JPA to lock on the query for addresses but it seems that's not allowed because the authors have incorrectly (in my opinion) decided that locking the parent should be sufficient.

So instead I will either be using `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level or `QueryHints.LEFT_FETCH` set to `a.addresses` so that the addressses are queried and lockeed during the account fetch.